# DialogFlow "preview intent" without causing fulfilment

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is there a way to preview the intent response with confidence score without actually triggering parameters to be filled, possible fulfilment web hooks to be called, etc.

I know Amazon Lex has a "preview intent" call that lets you preview what the response might be before actually doing the official call for a response/fulfillment.

I'm trying to be able to filter the the responses from multiple bots and choose the one with the highest confidence score and I don't want to trigger fulfilment for any bot that isn't going to be used in the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogflow as of today, does not provide an option to predict the response of an intent before it is being triggered.

Dialogflow ES has [Intent matching](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-matching), and you might be able to do something like the [next-best-intents solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59974742/dialogflow-suggest-the-next-best-intents-as-a-response), if that helps.